# Container based authentication not working in tomcat 7.0

Tags: tomcat

I had installed Tomcat 7.0 and apache axis2 in my laptop.  I had deployed 
a simple SOAP based web services. Web services deployment successful and there is not error in log files and also getting successful message. 
When I try to implement Tomcat container based authentication (basic)
using web.xml, it is not working. All proper libraries exists in lib folder.

### My web.xml entries as below.

```
<security-role>
          <description>Normal operator user</description>
          <role-name>operator</role-name>
    </security-role>

    <security-constraint>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>Operator Roles Security</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>

        <auth-constraint>
            <role-name>operator</role-name>
        </auth-constraint>
        <user-data-constraint>
            <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
        </user-data-constraint>
    </security-constraint>

    <login-config>
         <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
         <role-name>operator</role-name>
    </login-config>

       <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>com.kathy.ws.UserProfile</servlet-name>
          <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
       </servlet-mapping>
----------------------------------------tomcat users.xml--------
  <role rolename="tomcat"/>
  <role rolename="operator"/>
  <user username="tomcat" password="welcome1" roles="tomcat"/>
  <user username="both" password="welcome1" roles="tomcat,operator"/>
  <user username="operator" password="welcome1" roles="operator"/>
-------------------------sun-jaxws.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<endpoints
  xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jax-ws/ri/runtime"
  version="2.0">
  <endpoint
      name="UserProfileImpl"
      implementation="com.kathy.ws.UserProfile"
      url-pattern="/services/UserProfile"/>
 </endpoint>

</endpoints>
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: I do not get any error.It is not UserProfileImpl ->UserProfile

Comment: No errors in log files.  UserProfile  Hi there, this is an AXIS service!
Perhaps there will be a form for invoking the service here...

Comment: When I open browser and localhost:8080/security-test/services/UserProfile  -->  axis2 pop up successful message as above.